# Windows Phone 8.1 CameraButton Alternative?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Long story short, I'm a) Building a Windows Universal App and b) Want to use the Default (read: hardware) camera/shutter button.

Specifically, I'm looking for something akin to [CameraButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.camerabuttons(v=vs.105).aspx) from Microsoft.Device (Note: adding it will mess up with mscorlib which means Msoft won't support.)

Unfortunately I've seemed upon a snag - I've found a lack of replacements, or even documentation.

Naturally my first recourse was teh googlez, after which I perused the Windows.Phone dll but to no avail.

So the question is... does an alternative exist?  Will have I have to roll my own freaking dll just to use a hardware button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Windows Phone Runtime app use the [HardwareButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.aspx) class and its CameraPressed, CameraHalfPressed, and CameraReleased events.

An easy way to find classes relevant to your app's frameworks is to open the Object Browser in your Visual Studio project and scope it to "My Solution" to search just available classes and methods.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, although I'll say the UI Namespace is quite... misleading...